What is $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(a\cos x,a\sin x)}{a^2}dx$?
I came up with this while messing around with the $\gcd$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$ functions in Desmos.
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(a\cos x,a\sin x)}{a^2}dx$$
The function inside the integral always has a slope of $0$ but is very discontinuous. At higher values of $a$ it seems to approximate $\frac{\sin 2x}{2}$ with fewer lines approximating $\frac{\sin 2x}{4},\frac{\sin 2x}{6},$ and so on as pictured below for $a=100$.

Some more things I noticed (mostly through experimentation):

$I$ is undefined when $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}<a<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. I can not find any other values of $a$ that make $I$ undefined.
$I(\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=0$
$I(a)=2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(a\cos x,a\sin x)}{a^2}dx$
The integrand turns into $3$ parts at $a=\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$, $2$ parts again back at $a=\sqrt{\frac{9}{2}}$.
In fact, every time it changes how many parts it is made up of seems to be at $a=\sqrt{\frac{b}{2}}$ where $b$ is an odd number. I suspect the pattern is $b_n=1,5,9,...,4n-3$.

As for actually evaluating the integral, I really don't know how to proceed.

EDIT:
It seems that Desmos defines $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ as $\operatorname{lcm}(\lfloor a+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor,\lfloor b+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor)$. This seems like it should help significantly but I still am unsure of how to proceed.

EDIT 2:
I simplified(?) it into this integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{a^{2}}\frac{cs}{c-cs+s+2\sum_{k=1}^{c-1}\lfloor\frac{ks}{c}\rfloor}dx$$
where $s=\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+a\sin x\rfloor$ and $c=\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+a\cos x\rfloor$

What does LCM mean for real numbers?

You can just use \operatorname to make a custom math function render.

You have said in the question that the function is not continuous. What makes you think that it can be integrated?

@RedFive I believe it is defined on every point in the integral bounds aside from the values of a I had mentioned above.

Why have I received a downvote?

I didn't downvote, but until you tell us how LCM is defined for non-integer arguments, this is an incomplete question. Desmos might know a definition for what $lcm(\pi,e)$ is equal to, but it is non-standard, so we don't.

The down vote was not mine either - I like to ask clarifying questions with an open mind and to be honest, I actually find this question interesting.

@ThomasAndrews Thanks, I managed to figure it out and added it to an edit at the bottom of my post

@RedFive Thanks! I really appreciate when people ask clarifying questions because most of my posts are way over my math ability level and the questions help me better understand what I'm actually asking.

Some quick numerical approximations suggest that the integral has value $\approx \frac12$ for $a \gg 0$.

@TravisWillse By $a\gg0$ did you mean $a\gg1$?

@J.G. Yes, that was my intent.

It would be helpful to make a table of values for fixed $a$.

The third point can be shown simply by symmetry. Using the third point, the first point is easy to address since $\operatorname{lcm}$ is undefined when both parameters are zero. Assuming $a>0$, as $\lfloor a\sin x+1/2\rfloor\le\lfloor a/\sqrt2+1/2\rfloor$ for $x\in[0,\pi/4]$ and likewise for $\cos$, the integral is undefined when $a/\sqrt2<1/2$. The same argument holds when $a<0$. The second point follows since $\operatorname{lcm}$ is only defined at the point $x=\pi/4$ so the integral is zero there.

@TravisWillse This is a plot of $I(a)$ for $1\le a\le10^{30}$.

In this answer I'll cover an explanation to all points mentioned in the question, first of all lets grab the basics here.
An explanation to what will the value become as a gets large(a>>1) will be included at last.

we see these different $\frac{\sin 2x}{2k}$ graphs because gcd of the two terms (that is k here) takes different values (k=1,2,3,...) at different points, each gives a separate graph.

2)Explanation to points mentioned by you:
i) I is undefined for $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}<a<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ because at these values, $\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+a\cos x\rfloor$ and the other term both do not become nonzero at any point x in the range , but lcm(any number,0) is not defined at any point in the range ,thus it gives undefined.
ii) $I(\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=0$ can be explained as the desmos app just integrates in the part of domain only, and at these values of a ,domain is just a point in x ( x= pi/4 ), thus it has an integral of zero ( due to integral of just a point yielding 0 ).
iii)$I(a)=2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(a\cos x,a\sin x)}{a^2}dx$ is due to symmetry along $\pi/4$
iv)the changes in the number of lines is due to introduction of new values of
$\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+a\cos x\rfloor$ thus creating new lcm
Now as to the integral , computing such a piecewise integral has to be done one by one and can't be coined into a simple formula.
For large values of a too, the integral varies by a significant amount as a is changed by just +1 , this behavior is because of the fact that lcm of two numbers changes drastically when we change one of the numbers even by a small amount (for eg. lcm(6,60) = 60 but lcm(6,61) = 366 ) , so when we change a , we are changing the value of the integrand by significant amounts at many intervals thus we see a huge change.
From this it is clear that the value of the integral will tend to oscillate at different a and will not settle (converge) to a single value at large a.
==>> So one thing we could compute is the average value of integral at large a:
we take the average of integral from a=A to a=A+k where A>> k >>1
, averaging out for a= A+i where i belongs in 0 to k
one quick observation would be that the number and location of discontinuities in the integrand will remain almost same as we change i because k<<A , so we assume k is so small as compared to A that the intervals of continuity remain the same.
Talking about any one such interval where graph remains continuous , the two numbers whose lcm we are taking are going to change as we change 'i' , because our sample space for i's is large (k>>1) , it is fair to assume the factors of each of these numbers are totally random.
Thus in this interval ,let $\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+a\cos x\rfloor$ = m and $\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+a\sin x\rfloor$ = n , we have the probability of them having 2 as a common factor = (probab of 2 dividing m) * (probab of 2 dividing n) = 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4
(See that as per assumptions, it has to be independent of A and i)
Similarly for any prime P , the probability of m and n having P as a common factor = 1/P * 1/P = $\frac{1}{P^2}$
So , more generally ,let the two numbers have a gcd of $$\alpha=2^{\gamma1}\cdot3^{\gamma2}\cdot5^{\gamma3}*\dots p_n^{\gamma_n}$$
(just a prime factorization of the gcd) all bases are primes.
What is the probability of this gcd occuring , it is $$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{{\alpha}^2}\cdot\left(1-\sum\frac{1}{p_i^2}+\sum\frac{1}{p_i^2\cdot p_j^2}-\dots\right)\cdot{\prod{\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)}}\end{align*} $$ where 'p' are all those primes which do not divide $\alpha$ and all $p_i$ divide it and $j \neq i$
We can easily observe it all becomes $$ = \frac{1}{{\alpha}^2}* {\prod{(1-\frac{1}{P^2})}}$$ where P are all primes
A small explanation to this: each term $(1-\frac{1}{p^2})$ is the probability of p not being a prime factor of gcd , and product of these is the probability of having none of these p as prime factors of gcd. the term $\frac{1}{{\alpha}^2}$ is the probability of $\alpha$ being present in the gcd, and the term $(1-\sum\frac{1}{p_i^2}+\sum\frac{1}{p_i^2*p_j^2}-...)$ is the probability of gcd not containing any higher powers of any primes than those $\alpha$ contains(given that $\alpha$ divides gcd).
lets call this probability PGCD($\alpha$)
Now , moving on to final values
We have, for this interval the expected value of integrand (i.e. the average value of integrand for all different 'i' ) will be $$ = m*n*PGCD(1) + m*n*(1/2)*PGCD(2) + m*n*(1/3)*PGCD(3) + .. + m*n*(1/t)*PGCD(t) +... $$ for all natural numbers 't'
This can also be written as $$ = m*n* (\sum(\frac{1}{t}*PGCD(t)))$$
plugging in the PGCD(t) formula we get a sum of product series'
we can use the eulers's product formula to compute the infinite products (you can check out here reimann zeta wikipedia and euler product wiki)
expected value comes out to $$m*n* \frac{6}{{\pi}^2} * \sum{\frac{1}{t^3}}$$ $$ \approx m*n*(0.730) $$
So average integral is the integral of expected values over the interval 0 to $\pi/2$ $$ = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{0.730*(a\cos x*a\sin x)}{a^2}dx $$
$$ \approx 0.365$$
Pointing out any mistakes and asking something which was unclear is highly encouraged.

I've looked this problem, and have a few more notes too long for a comment. But overall, I'm pessimistic about there being an exact closed form much simpler than just evaluating the integral directly. First, we have $I(-a)=I(a)$ for all $a$ where both are defined: $$\begin{split}I(-a)&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(\lfloor-a\cos x+\frac12\rfloor,\lfloor-a\sin x+\frac12\rfloor)}{(-a)^2}\,dx\\&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(-\lceil a\cos x-\frac12\rceil,-\lceil a\sin x-\frac12\rceil)}{a^2}\,dx\\&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(\lceil a\cos x-\frac12\rceil,\lceil a\sin x-\frac12\rceil)}{a^2}\,dx\\&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(\lfloor a\cos x+\frac12\rfloor,\lfloor a\sin x+\frac12\rfloor)}{a^2}\,dx\\&=I(a).\end{split}$$ (The last equality holds since $\lceil x\rceil=\lfloor x+1\rfloor$ for all non-integer $x$.) Therefore, without loss of generality, we can assume that $a\geq0$.
Now, let's look closer at the segments of the integrand. For all $0\leq m\leq\lfloor a+\frac12\rfloor,0\leq n\leq\lfloor a+\frac12\rfloor,0\leq x\leq\frac\pi2$, we have $m=\lfloor a\cos x+\frac12\rfloor$ iff $\cos^{-1}(\frac{m+1/2}a)<x\leq\cos^{-1}(\frac{m-1/2}a)$, and $n=\lfloor a\sin x+\frac12\rfloor$ iff $\sin^{-1}(\frac{n-1/2}a)\leq x<\sin^{-1}(\frac{n+1/2}a)$. (For the purposes of these inequalities, $\sin^{-1}$ and $\cos^{-1}$ are presumed to continue monotonically outside the domain of $[0,1]$; the exact values are unimportant, since they can only occur outside the $0\leq x\leq\frac\pi2$ region.)
From our three inequalities for $x$, we can classify each segment based on which two values bound it, which in turn can be expressed in terms of $m$ and $n$. In particular, we have:
$$\begin{cases}x\in[0,\tfrac\pi2]&\text{if }a-\tfrac12<m\leq\tfrac12,a-\tfrac12<n\leq\tfrac12\\x\in[0,\cos^{-1}(\tfrac{m-1/2}a)]&\text{if }\max(\tfrac12,a-\tfrac12)<m\leq a+\tfrac12,-\tfrac12\leq n\leq\tfrac12,(m-\tfrac12)^2+(n+\tfrac12)^2>a^2\\x\in[\sin^{-1}(\tfrac{n-1/2}a),\tfrac\pi2]&\text{if }-\tfrac12\leq m\leq\tfrac12,\max(\tfrac12,a-\tfrac12)<n\leq a+\tfrac12,(m+\tfrac12)^2+(n-\tfrac12)^2>a^2\\x\in[0,\sin^{-1}(\tfrac{n+1/2}a))&\text{if }a-\tfrac12<m\leq a+\tfrac12,-\tfrac12<n\leq\min(\tfrac12,a-\tfrac12),(m-\tfrac12)^2+(n+\tfrac12)^2\leq a^2\\x\in(\cos^{-1}(\tfrac{m+1/2}a),\tfrac\pi2]&\text{if }-\tfrac12<m\leq\min(\tfrac12,a-\tfrac12),a-\tfrac12<n\leq a+\tfrac12,(m+\tfrac12)^2+(n-\tfrac12)^2\leq a^2\\x\in[\sin^{-1}(\tfrac{n-1/2}a),\cos^{-1}(\tfrac{m-1/2}a)]&\text{if }\tfrac12<m\leq a+\tfrac12,\tfrac12<n\leq a+\tfrac12,(m+\tfrac12)^2+(n-\tfrac12)^2>a^2,(m-\tfrac12)^2+(n-\tfrac12)^2\leq a^2,(m-\tfrac12)^2+(n+\tfrac12)^2>a^2\\x\in[\sin^{-1}(\tfrac{n-1/2}a),\sin^{-1}(\tfrac{n+1/2}a))&\text{if }-\tfrac12\leq m\leq a+\tfrac12,\tfrac12<n\leq a-\tfrac12,(m+\tfrac12)^2+(n-\tfrac12)^2>a^2,(m-\tfrac12)^2+(n+\tfrac12)^2\leq a^2\\x\in(\cos^{-1}(\tfrac{m+1/2}a),\cos^{-1}(\tfrac{m-1/2}a)]&\text{if }\tfrac12<m\leq a-\tfrac12,-\tfrac12\leq n\leq a+\tfrac12,(m+\tfrac12)^2+(n-\tfrac12)^2\leq a^2,(m-\tfrac12)^2+(n+\tfrac12)^2>a^2\\x\in(\cos^{-1}(\tfrac{m+1/2}a),\sin^{-1}(\tfrac{n+1/2}a))&\text{if }-\tfrac12\leq m\leq a-\tfrac12,-\tfrac12\leq n\leq a-\tfrac12,(m+\tfrac12)^2+(n-\tfrac12)^2\leq a^2,(m+\tfrac12)^2+(n+\tfrac12)^2>a^2,(m-\tfrac12)^2+(n+\tfrac12)^2\leq a^2.\end{cases}$$
This formulation explains why the segments of $I(a)$ change when $a=\frac12\sqrt k$: at these points, some $(m,n)$ pairs will start or stop satisfying the quadratic inequalities. However, it also shows why computing $I(a)$ exactly is nontrivial, since there's no easy way to enumerate all the $(m,n)$ pairs in each class. If we did have such an enumeration, then we could write $$I(a)=\frac1{a^2}\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor a+\frac12\rfloor}\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor a+\frac12\rfloor}\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)\Delta x_a(m,n)$$ where $\Delta x_a(m,n)$ is the width of the interval corresponding to $(m,n)$, or $0$ if there isn't one.
